# Which Mac is good enough for iOS development?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Are you an iOS development? Please tell me which mac hardware is good enough for that. I am gonna use it in about 3 years or more. I am intended to buy a macbook pro 2015 with 13.3", core i5, RAM 8GB, SSD 128GB. It's not so expensive but of course not cheap for me. I am just a student in an university right now, i haven't earned money so i want to save money as much as possible, but it should work well. That hardware is okay or can be less? I know that is an old question but i want to make sure before buying one. Thank you so so much for helping me.

Comment: The model you mentioned is enough, but you can also go for any mac laptop (pro, air and even the new macbook) just remember that xCode uses a lot of memory so I advise you to get 8Gb RAM and enough disk space for your projects

Comment: You're on a computer right now. Are you sure it won't do the job? Also, does your university have a computer lab with iOS development tools you're allowed to use?

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Late 2011 MacBook Pro 15" with 4GB of memory and a 750GB hard drive (non-SSD). Xcode 7 is slower than previous versions (especially the emulator) but usable.

But using an SSD on a laptop with 8GB memory is more than up to the task of developing for Mac OS X or iOS.

Some points to consider:

1) 128GB storage is not large so you will probably need more external storage depending on what you download and store on your laptop.
2) While 8GB memory should be fine for 3 years (at least), if the memory cannot be upgraded after purchase then consider 16GB memory if you can afford it.

One annoyance I find, when developing, is that you can always use more screen space. You will find yourself opening and closing a lot of panes / windows in Xcode on a 13.3" display.

Comment: Eh... 128 GB is fine. It's not a lot, sure, but he's only doing iOS development and regular stuff. Unless he's installing a *lot* of extraneous applications or Windows VMs that shouldn't be an issue. Also, so long as he occasionally power cycles his machine and doesn't keep an insane number of browser tabs open, it doesn't feel likely that 8 GB will ever be a legitimate bottleneck.